# How to make div not take up space when completed animation using CSS only?

Tags: css, animation, animate.css

I am using Animate.css to make a div slide up vertically and disappear. The slide out animation works BUT it preserves the div's original space. Is there a way to make the div not take up space when its completed its slide out animation?

Note I know why this is occurring (animate.css uses translate3d instead of height/max-height). So I know I can write my own slide out animation but I want to keep using animate.css because its got many, many useful animations. I just need to figure out a way to make the div not take up space when its completed its slide out/fade out/bounce out/etc animations? If I can't figure out a way to do this I gotta write all my own custom animations for bounce, fade, zoom, slide. I just wanna use animate.css (unless anyone knows of a better css animation library?)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>Some text above</p>
<div class="animate__animated animate__slideOutUp" style="background-color: red">I will slide up</div>
<p>Some text below. I should move up when the above div slides out</p>
```

Comment: it's clear that you need for sure to change to something else. animate.css is not suitable for you and you won't be able to find a generic solution that works for all the defined animations

Answer (score -1):

What about `.fadeOutUp` instead of `.slideOutUp`, works form you?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>Some text above</p>
<div class="animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp" style="background-color: red">I will slide up</div>
<p>Some text below. I should move up when the above div slides out</p>
```